# perl does not evaluate bash script correctly

Tags: linux, bash, perl

This is my code

```
my $shell_line_diff=`echo $(($(diff -U 0 ftest1.txt ftest2.txt|grep ^\+|wc -l)-$(diff -U 0 ftest1.txt ftest2.txt|grep ^\-|wc -l)))`;
print "difference in the number of lines is $shell_line_diff\n";
```

and the evaluated script works fine on Linux bash.

But in perl it gives me the following results:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `echo 1010 1010 10000000 10000003 10000004 10000010(1010 1010 10000000 10000003 10000004 10000010diff -U 0 ftest1.txt ftest2.txt|grep ^+|wc -l)-1010 1010 10000000 10000003 10000004 10000010diff -U 0 ftest1.txt ftest2.txt|grep ^-|wc -l)))'
difference in the number of lines is
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you supposed to have two opening brackets `(`?

Comment: You're pushing an awful lot of work that you can do directly in Perl out to the shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your shell command is not quoted.
Use temporary variable like this:

```
my $cmd = 'echo $(($(diff -U 0 ftest1.txt ftest2.txt|grep ^\+|wc -l)-$(diff -U 0 ftest1.txt ftest2.txt|grep ^\-|wc -l)))';
my $shell_line_diff=`$cmd`;
print "difference in the number of lines is $shell_line_diff\n";
```

If you do not quote it properly, `$(` is interpreted by perl before execute your backtick command (see `man perlvar`).

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the actual problem with the code, I would simplify this to

```
my @lines = qx/diff -U 0 ftest1.txt ftest2.txt/
my $shell_line_diff = grep(/^\+/, @lines) - grep(/^-/, @lines)
```

This should be much faster, as you are

1. Only running `diff` once, not twice
2. Eliminating several unnecessary processes by not running `grep`, `wc`, or the command substitutions that pass the results of the pipelines to the shell's arithmetic expression.

If you really want to keep the shell, you can drop the `wc -l` command in favor of the `-c` option to `grep`, which produces a line count instead of the actual set of lines.